# Saving a macro so that the file can be updated

Tags: excel, vba

- Background Information - I have two buttons, that both run a set of code. The excel file has over 30 columns and 65,000 rows. This file is exported (.csv) from somewhere and is updated biweekly.
- Goal - have the new file saved with the same name as the old. So that the values can be updated, buttons are still available and the code can run again with the new file.
- **Or** That when a new file is exported, it is saved in a folder that runs the code **INDEPENDENT** of the user path. i.e     `Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "C:\Users\"this can be any name"\Desktop\Downloads\"`

Attempt

1. Used a similar code to the one in a previous question "Run same excel macro on multiple excel files" with edits to tailor for my code. With no success

   ```
   Sub ProcessFiles()
       Dim Filename, Pathname As String
       Dim wb As Workbook

       Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Files\"
       Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xls")
       Do While Filename <> ""
           Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
           DoWork wb
           wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
           Filename = Dir()
       Loop
   End Sub
   ```

   2. Currently, when I attempt the first method I only replace (Old file + VBA) with (New file).

Please note that the solution does not need to be a VBA code. If it's just saving the file in a new method that stores the macro and updates the values I would be happy.

Comment: What you are asking and what you are doing in your code are a bit different... or I'm not following your question. What I understand is that you would like to process and save the workbook in which you have the macro, and save a copy of it (and still contain the macro). Your code opens a different workbook that does not contain the macro... so when saved, it won't have it either (unless you are inserting it in the `DoWork wb` procedure...

Comment: @DarXyde please ignore what I'm doing, as I'm new to VBA. Your understanding is correct. I would like to save the MACRO in a way that when I open new files of the same format, it would still work. Right now I have the old file with the code, I would like to update the file and maintain my code and buttons.

Comment: I would do all the changes via the macro, and at the end instead of `.Save`, use a `.SaveAs`. [more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas). This will not save the changes in your old version, but in the new version. I will add an answer with a sample.

Answer (score 0):

An example of my previous answer:

```
Sub SaveThisAs()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'ThisWorkbook referrs to the workbook the macro is ran from
    Dim PathToSaveTo As String

    PathToSaveTo = wb.Path & "\"
    PathToSaveTo = PathToSaveTo & Format(Now, "ddMMyyyy_hhmmss") & wb.Name  'Lets add a timestamp

    'Do your macro stuff here
    '....


    'Save the workbook
    wb.SaveAs PathToSaveTo

End Sub
```

Please note that I'm using `wb.Name` at the end of the file to save to... this will be fine first time you run this, but a second time the name will get longer... and longer ...  and longer. Adjust as per your needs with an appropriate file name.

Comment: I have been testing your code.  Let me test the logic here. Once I save my file with the macro. If I open another file and name it same name, I will get a prompt response of "replacing the file" which I will click yes to. In which case my new file will have the macro from the file it just replaced. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, is a bit confusing what you are asking. With the code above it would be extremely unlikely to have the same name for your newly saved workbook, because I've added the timestamp in the filename, even if you change `wb.name` to a more fix name (i.e.: myworkbook.xlsm), the result will still be a different workbookname eachtime. If you want to completely replace the workbook, then just use the same name for the variable `PathToSaveTo = wb.Path & "\myworkbook.xlsm"` but that would defeat the purpose of keeping the older version with a different name. Maybe try to clarify your question better